# getting error while installing react-native application on android device

Tags: android, react-native

i am installing the react-native application on android but it is showing me the same error every time. once it was installed then disconnects and later its the same error then create new project but results remain same

[it is the error even i have tried differnt sdk tools but notihng changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iolbO.png)[the doctor displaying version 33.0.0 while it is already installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORosj.png)